# VolumeBackendAPIException: Bad or unexpected response from the storage volume backend API

Tags: python, server

I am trying pyu4v.

Sample python script to create a new storage group and assign DailyDefault and HourlyDefault existing snapshot policies.
[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvr8n.png)

the error message is:
`VolumeBackendAPIException: Bad or unexpected response from the storage volume backend API: Error GET symmetrix. The status code received is 403 and the message is None.`

[Python SDK](https://infohub.delltechnologies.com/l/dell-emc-powermax-and-vmax-all-flash-snapshot-policies-2/appendix-b-rest-api-examples-2/)

Is this a code problem or a server problem?
Maybe the volume is being formatted?